# Tensorflow: ValueError: Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference, but saw value None

Tags: tensorflow

Here's the example codes:

```
class Model:

def __init__(self, config):
    inputs = self.get_inputs()
    outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            cell=tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(config.hidden_dim, state_is_tuple=True),
            inputs=inputs,
            dtype=tf.float32)

def get_inputs(self):
    # do something to archive the inputs, 
    # which are not just the word embeddings,
    # rather, they are the outputs of another
    # model. The shape is (batch_size, ?, hidden_dim),
    # ? means the maxlength for each batch depends
    # on the data.
```

However, when I trained my model, I got this error:

`Tensorflow: ValueError: Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference, but saw value None.`

I assume it's the variable maxlength that causes the problem. Do I need to write my own LSTM for my model or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: maxlength shouldn't cause the issue. Are you sure the size of the last dimension of your input is well defined?

Comment: I know this topic is not active for a long time but posting just for future googlers. I've faced a similar issue when I tried to stack CNN with bi-LSTM. After printing tensor shapes, it became clear that CNN `output` somehow "forgets" its shape information. (It just prints [None, None, None] while in fact the dimension is known to it) So before feeding the output into LSTM layer, I set the "shape information" using `output.set_shape()` [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape).

Comment: @emrekgn, thanks a lot for your comment. It solved a similar problem to me and I am sure it will continue to help a lot of other people in the future. Maybe put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The last dimension of `inputs` has to be known already when compiling the graph. You can check this by printing its static shape:

```
print(inputs.get_shape())
```

What you probably see is that the last dimension is `?` meaning that TensorFlow was unable to infer it. You said that the shape of the inputs is always `[batch_size, ?, hidden_dim]`. However, TensorFlow is not necessarily able to infer `hidden_dim`. The level of intelligence that TensorFlow has for infering the output shape of different operations varies between TensorFlow versions.

You can fix the problem by explicitly telling the dimensionality of the inputs to TensorFlow. Before calling `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`, set the shape of the inputs using`inputs.set_shape(shape)`. It works like `inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, shape)`, but it only sets the static shape. If some dimensions of `shape` are `None`, they won't be altered:

```
inputs.set_shape([None, None, hidden_dim])
```